# What to do with reworked/remastered games?

Tags: discussion, tags

Recently, games are being reworked because of it's a very good game or a very classic game. I just don't know how to address them.

One example is "Fable Anniversary", it's 'Fable 1' or 'Fable - The Lost Chapters', and we don't have many questions in that area. But it's still valid questions right?

Comment: WHat would you like to know about how we handle them?

Comment: do we create new tags for them and something like that?

Comment: I raised a request regarding the re-release of Age of Empires II, as I think the current tagging system of having 2 different tags is confusing (http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10320/age-of-empires-ii-hd-merge-request)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is... It Depends.

Specifically, it depends on if the game is a Remake or a Remaster.

So, what exactly is the difference?

### Remakes

Remakes take the core concepts and/or story of the game and rework how it plays.

Examples of Remakes are: Shadowgate 2014 and Metroid: Zero Mission.

For these, each version should have their own tag as the questions for one will not be related to the questions for the other.

### Remasters

Remasters do not change the core game, they only update it with new graphics, sounds, and controls.

Examples of Remasters are:  Secret of Monkey Island: Special Edition and Grim Fandango Remastered.

Remasters should **not** have their own tags unless it is something specific to the version, such as a technical support type question or how to switch control schemes.

Comment: But what about the example in the question (Fable) where 95% of the game is a remaster, but there's a bit of extra content added on?

Answer (score -3):

Personally, I believe that each game should have its own tag and not each version/re-release.

If each version had its own tag it becomes hard to follow the tag (well, you need to follow multiple tags when you only want to be aware of anything to do with `Fable 1` as in your example).

Additionally, a question could potentially be tagged against one of the multiple versions on offer therefore people following one version of the tag would miss the question.

If a question is specific to a certain version it can be added to the question (e.g. *only occurs in ...*).  Otherwise, we can safely assume the question relates to any version of the game in question.

Unless someone can provide an example where a game should be split up I don't see a feasible alternative.  Look at existing tags for Half Life and Monkey Island where questions can be safely asked regarding different versions without needing additional tags.

Comment: Not every version of a game needs a version tag I agree there, but to blanket-apply this to every game version is wrong - there ARE games that DO differ between versions, for example: Sonic 3, Sonic & Knuckles, and Sonic 3 and Knuckles: If the player owns a copy of Sonic & Knuckles, they can attach it to their Sonic 3 cartridge in order to play through both games end-to-end as "Sonic 3 & Knuckles". This allows for scenarios that are not possible in the individual games, such as playing Sonic 3 levels as Knuckles or Sonic & Knuckles levels as Tails or the combination of Sonic and Tails.

Comment: @Robotnik - I agree with your examples given.  My concern is more with the potential release of say Sonic 3 HD.  The game being exactly the same but for updated graphics.  All Sonic 3 HD questions could go into the Sonic 3 tag, rather than maintaining separate tags.  With separate tags, there is a good chance that a lot of questions would apply to both tags.

Comment: That's not what your answer currently says. If you are explicitly concerned with straight "HD rereleases" and not necessarily different versions of a game, you should state that. Currently, the way your answer is written, would mean combining Sonic 3, Sonic & Knuckles and Sonic 3 & Knuckles into the same tag (as well as other games that differ between versions). Further: What if the "Sonic 3 HD" version had bonus levels? or new enemies or mechanics? (cont.)

Comment: This happened with [Golden Axe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Axe) for example - where 're-releases' had a completely new level and boss. The other problem is, where do we draw the line? The recent Call of Duty games are basically reskins of each other with a new storyline and weapons right? Should we combine them as well? Look, all I'm saying is at the moment, your answer would currently see ALL game versions merged into the same game tag, which I think is wrong. I think it should happen on a case-by-case basis.