# Age of Empires II HD merge request

Tags: discussion, tag-merging

It is a little confusing having 2 tags for the Age of Empires II game (one for the HD release).  There doesn't appear to be a running theme for other games that have been "re-mastered" or "re-released".

Related to this unanswered question:
[What to do with reworked/remastered games?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10065/what-to-do-with-reworked-remastered-games)

In regards to the situation with Age of Empires II, we have questions in the [age-of-empires-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/age-of-empires-2) tag that would also be relevant to the [age-of-empires-2-hd](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/age-of-empires-2-hd) tag but are marked as [age-of-empires-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/age-of-empires-2) only.  For example, several questions regarding online play (where to play, lag issues etc) that don't always include the [age-of-empires-2-hd](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/age-of-empires-2-hd) tag.

The key difference between both games is really down to the Steam features/platform.  Nothing in-game (campaign, units etc) is different, with the exception of the Forgotten DLC (although this started as a mod on the original game).

Would it not be better to simply merge [age-of-empires-2-hd](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/age-of-empires-2-hd) into [age-of-empires-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/age-of-empires-2), and for any of these merges also add a [steam](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steam) tag if it is missing (not missing in all cases)?  For the purpose of people following the tags - do they *really* need to follow 2 different tags?  What purpose would there be to only follow 1 of the 2 tags?

Look at the Monkey Island vs. Special Edition release.  The game has one tag, and you can clearly see the questions that are specific to the SE version by scanning through the questions.  Same goes for Half-Life 1 having 1 tag, despite the game having arguably 3 different versions (original disk, Steam release and Source release).

Comment: You can use the formatting `[tag:tagname]` in questions, which will format the tags to look and act like the tags on a question, including acting as links to the tag page :)

Comment: Isn't the *AOE2: The Forgotten* expansion pack exclusive to the HD version? If yes, that could be a reason to have them tagged separately.

Comment: @galacticninja - technically no, as it started as a mod on the original release

Comment: @galacticninja - also, there are no questions specific to that DLC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I (now) don't believe that this is a request worth doing.  Having distinct tags for specific releases does seem useful **but only when the releases are functionally different**. As galacticninja pointed out in the comments, there are functional differences (in the DLC) as well as specific questions regarding online play only relevant to the HD version.

Comment: This is also what I get from Virusboy' answer, which was posted around half a year ago.

Comment: @timelord64 nope the other answer was based on file where mine was about in game content

Answer (score 3):

Bad idea, both releases have different files, and were built differently.  AOE2 requires a different Direct X then the HD built version, so if Joan Of Arc comes in and asks why doesnt my pc render AOE2 properly, then the tag AOE2 HD would not fit at all.
Remember one was built for the 98 era the other for the Win 8.1 era.  This alone requires 2 tags.  Not to mention the gfx files.