# 'Skyrim Special Edition' question handling

Tags: discussion, tags

As the Skyrim remaster is out today, we need to determine how to tag it.

According to [this discussion](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10065/what-to-do-with-reworked-remastered-games), it should get a new tag if it's a rework with new mechanics, but it shouldn't get a new tag if it's just updated graphics.

Which category is the new version of Skyrim?

Comment: The linked [dupe question](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10065/what-to-do-with-reworked-remastered-games) is a nice resource, but I don't know enough about Skyrim to use that question to figure out whether we need a new tag or not. So I'm going to reopen this question as a discussion about "which category does this version of Skyrim fall into", not "what do we do about remakes in general".

Comment: Without playing the game just yet, I can't say for sure if mechanics have changed vs. just graphics/PC architecture updates. But, considering the Unofficial Skyrim Patch has been ported to the new game, I would say that no, Bethesda hasn't fixed much.

Comment: I haven't played the game yet so your my only source.

Comment: From what I've gathered so far from Youtube is that it's mostly performance/graphical ugrades, along with the ability to pick up an item from a character you kill early on (that one could argue is just a bugfix)

Comment: I think that since there's no gameplay differences, it should be the same tag, but it's also likely going to be important for the OP to state which one they are using if the question is about modding or technical issues

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As of this writing, we have two questions about original *Skyrim* vs. *Skyrim: Special Edition*:

- [Are there any differences between Skyrim & Skyrim: Special Edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/289683/what-are-the-differences-between-skyrim-skyrim-special-edition)
- [Are there any different quests in Skyrim, Special Edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/289624/are-there-any-different-quests-in-skyrim-special-edition)

Both of these answers indicate that the story content is exactly the same. Graphics are improved and PC mods may need to be recompiled *only if* the new graphical improvements affect them. Console versions support mods. Other changes are cosmetic.

Because the differences are so minor, and the quests and such are unchanged, it seems to me that we should just keep using the tag [the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim) for both versions. This is consistent with how questions about "Special Editions" for other games are handled. For instance:

- [What is special about the "Steam Special Edition" of Tropico 3 and 4?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/132365/47878)
- [What's in Assassin's Creed Unity "special edition"?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/202892/47878)
- [If I buy Little Big Planet 2: Special Edition from Craigslist, will I still be able to use the "bonus content" offered from the Special Edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/73498/47878)
- [What are the bonuses of Dead Island Riptide Limited Edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/169438/47878)
- [Is there anything special about the Borderlands 2 GOTY edition over the base game with the same DLC?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/285831/47878)

All of these questions use the same tag as the original game.

Comment: I think that should be the rule I agree.

Comment: @LoreFriendly Are there a significant number of questions where SE/non-SE would actually make a difference? Tagging is about playing it by the numbers. (We could have a separate tag for each question, but that would be useless for organization/searching.)

Comment: @LoreFriendly Because the content is exactly the same, any content question while playing SE would be exactly the same answer for anyone playing original. Having separate tags would make it harder to find questions that are relevant to both editions and create unnecessary duplicates (e.g. we don't need "How do I solve quest X?" for both versions because the question, and answer, are each the same).

Comment: @LoreFriendly Has there been evidence of this happening? And if so, is it likely we will get enough questions about them to warrant its own tag?

Comment: Nexus mods, the most popular website for Skyrim mods is also not dividing Skyrim & Skyrim Special Edition.

Comment: @Oak that is not entirely true: see http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/ and http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/?

Comment: Nexus mods now splits the two. I have posted [a question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/322023/124847) that is specific to Skyrim Special Edition that I had to tag with just [Skyrim] because there is no [SKSE] or similar tag. That's clearly sub-optimal, but I don't know if a few questions like this is enough to justify a separate tag.

Answer (score 1):

Similarly — if this is still the consensus — let's merge [skyrim-anniversary-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skyrim-anniversary-edition) with [the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim).

The *Anniversary Edition* is basically the *Special Edition* with a lot of additional mods (74 mods from the Creation Club, both existing and unreleased ones).

<sup>[source](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/The_Elder_Scrolls_V:_Skyrim_Anniversary_Edition)</sup>