# Tags for NieR Replicant

Tags: discussion, tags

So, apparently *NieR Replicant* was a Japan-only release, which has recently been "updated" and released globally with the official title [*NieR Replicant™ ver.1.22474487139...*](https://store.steampowered.com/app/1113560/NieR_Replicant_ver122474487139/).

Should questions about this game be tagged [nier-replicant-1.22474487139](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nier-replicant-1.22474487139) to distinguish it from the previous release, [nier-replicant](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nier-replicant), and/or [nier](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nier)?

Comment: Do you mean [like this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/385392/143571)?

Comment: I was about to say that it's officially abbreviated as "NieR Replicant ver.1.22..." but I didn't realize the full one fits

Comment: When I created the tag, I added `-1.22474487139` remove any ambiguity between the original and remaster. However since there are no questions tagged to `nier-replicant`, I'd be ok with shortening it

Comment: Whatever the base tag ends up being, it should probably be fairly heavily synonymized

Comment: I think the real tragedy is that we don’t have an answer to the weapon weight question

Comment: @Wondercricket what is actually different though, and would it ever really matter for tagging?

Comment: I'm assuming we should keep [tag:nier] as being just the first game, and not the series as a whole.

Comment: @OrangeDog To be honest, I am not sure if there are any differences (aside from graphics). I never played the original, so I can’t say one way or another

Comment: Related: https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10065/72346

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recording what I'm about to do for posterity, based on the comments, answer, and linked question.

Update [nier](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nier) description to clarify it's for all permutations of the original game, with [nier-replicant](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nier-replicant) and [nier-gestalt](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nier-gestalt) requested as synonyms. Keep [nier-replicant-1.22474487139](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nier-replicant-1.22474487139) as a separate tag to be used with it when the question is about the updated version, and [nier-replicant-1.22](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nier-replicant-1.22) as a synonym.

As far as I can see, there are no users with sufficient rep to make synonyms on these tags yet, so that will have to wait. Fortunately it's not much of a burden to do manually.

Comment: This is one of those situations where if you downvote you really need to explain it. We were trying to build a consensus here.

Answer (score 3):

After doing research between the four various titles - NieR, NieR: Replicant, NieR: Gestalt, NieR Replicant ver.1.22 - as well as additional information provided by Vemonus, [nier-replicant-1.22474487139](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nier-replicant-1.22474487139) needs to be a separate tag to differentiate it from the standard [nier](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nier)

> The 1.22474487139 version of Replicant contains exclusive content including a new story segment as well as a fifth ending

<strike>I believe it's safe to keep the base tag [nier](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nier), and create the following synonyms:</strike>

- [nier-replicant-1.22474487139](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nier-replicant-1.22474487139)
- [nier-replicant](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nier-replicant)
- [nier-gestalt](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nier-gestalt)

My researched concluded there are not enough (if any all) functionality or mechanical differences to warrant having separate tags for the various versions.

In Japan, NieR:Replicant and NieR:Gestalt were the same game with different titles for PS3 and X360 respectively. The only major difference was the main character's age and role to a secondary character. There were some minor differences as well, but nothing to suggest separating these tags.

Outside of Japan, the version titled NieR was simply the NieR:Gestalt version.

The globalized version of NieR:Replicant ver1.22474487139 is an HD Remaster of the Japan only version of NieR:Replicant, and my researched conducted only graphics and framerate are the only major differences.

Comment: The 1.22474487139 version of Replicant contains exclusive content including a new story segment as well as a fifth ending, so it definitely needs a new tag. Just my 2 cents. :)

Comment: @Vemonus so nier, nier-replicant and nier-gestalt are all functionally the same game, but -1.22 is different?

Comment: @OrangeDog 1.22474487139 is a remake of replicant (which is functionally the same as gestalt, just you play as brother Nier or daddy Nier, respectively). If it helps, 1.23474487139 is an approximation of the square root of 1.5. So basically it’s a pretentious way of saying it’s NieR RepliCant 1.5 ;)

Comment: @Vemonus you may be the only person who can propose synonyms on these tags, if you want to go ahead.